# Extract href from <a> tag with class uses Regex

Tags: python, regex, href

I need to read many pages from a website and extract all links with class "active" using a regex.
This tags can have the class attr BEFORE or AFTER the HREF value.

My code is:

```
    try:
        p = requests.get(url, timeout=4.0)
    except:
        p = None
    if p and p.content and p.status_code < 400:
        canonical_url = re.search('<a class="active" href="(.*)?"', p.content, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL|re.UNICODE)
```

but with this regex I can catch only links with class active BEFORE the HREF and not AFTER.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like python, you should tag this [tag:python]. Also, don't use regex. [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, but I need to use a regex.

Comment: Is there a reason why? Also, change `(.*)?` to `([^"]*)`

Comment: trying to understand why you would need to use a regex, could you give us more context around that please.

Comment: If it's a single site, and the structure is known (and regular), pulling out hrefs by using a regular expression is perfectly fine.

Comment: I used BS4, but my boss asked me to use regex because BS4 is an overkill to extract a simple link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the OP specified the following in the comments below the question, regex may be used. Be careful though as regex can easily *break* when trying to parse HTML.

> I used BS4, but my boss asked me to use regex because BS4 is an overkill to extract a simple link

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/FWihDJ/3)

```
<a\b(?=[^>]* class="[^"]*(?<=[" ])active[" ])(?=[^>]* href="([^"]*))
```

- `<a` Match this literally
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?=[^>]* class="[^"]*(?<=[" ])active[" ])` Positive lookahead ensuring the following is matched.

  - `[^>]*` Match any character except `>` any number of times
  - `class="` Match this literally
  - `[^"]*` Match any character except `"` any number of times
  - `(?<=[" ])` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a character in the set
  - `active` Match this literally
  - `[" ]` Match either character in the set
- `(?=[^>]* href="([^"]*))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `[^>]*` Match any character except `>` any number of times
  - `href="` Match this literally
  - `([^"]*)` Capture any character except `"` any number of times into capture group 1

Given the following samples, only the first 3 are matched:

```
<a class="active" href="something">
<a href="something" class="active">
<a href="something" class="another-class active some-other-class">

<a class="inactive" href="something">
<a not-class="active" href="something">
<a class="active" not-href="something">
```

Comment: Works perfectly! For Python I changed
<a\\b(?=[^>]* class=\"[^\"]*(?<=[\" ])active[\" ])(?=[^>]* href=\"([^\"]*))